# Stream collect groupingBy output customization

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, collectors

I have a JAVA class described as bellow:

```
public class Hello {
   
   public String field1;
   public String field2;
   public String field3;

}
```

Now I have a `list` of `Hello` objects, I want to group the list element by `field1`. My issue, I want to have only a set of `field3` as grouped elements, not all the `Hello` object fields.

For example, as output, I want to get a map:

```
field1Value1 -> [field3Value1, field3Value2, field3Value3]
field1Value2 -> [field3Value4, field3Value5, field3Value6]
```

I have tried to do it using steams of course:

```
HelloList.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hello::field1, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Like above I will get a set of `Hello` objects mapped by `field1`, unfortunately that's not what I want.

Comment: at least for me it's not really clear what you want, can you modify the question with some example

Comment: In the output map, I want the key to be field1 and a set of field3 as value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
helloList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Hello::field1, mapping(Hello::field3, toSet())));
```

In general, it's a good idea to have the Javadoc for `Collectors` handy, because there are a number of useful composition operations (such as this `mapping` and its inverse `collectingAndThen`), and there are enough that when you have a question like this it's useful to look over the list to find an appropriate tool.

Comment: It works, thank you. I'm going to take your advice into account.